# Can a localhost directly lead to an html file?

Tags: html, node.js, npm, localhost

total newbie to HTML here. I set up my localhost with an html file but i have to acess it with localhost:8080/filename.html. is there a way to access it directly with localhost:8080?

Comment: Name it `index.html`.

Comment: Depends on the webserver you are using. Since you tagged this [tag:node.js] I’m assuming you wrote your own using that. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit .htaccess file
2. Paste the following code at the beginning of the file changing the "filename.html" line with the page that you want to be served as your website's home page.

   `DirectoryIndex first.html`
3. You can also set more than one index files as your website's homepage.

   `DirectoryIndex home.html index.html index.php`

Comment: The `.htaccess` file will be read from left to right and the first available page will be selected. 

For example with the following code the files `home.html`, `index.html` and `index.php` will be added as the website's index pages. 

The server will look for the home.html file, if it is not found will continue to look for the `index.html` file etc.

    `DirectoryIndex home.html index.html index.php`

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your operating envionment you should be able to accomplish this with an htaccess file. In your root directory create a file named .htaccess

Add this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
DirectoryIndex filename.html
```

Comment: The question is tagged node.js and not apache

Comment: The use of mod_rewrite here appears to be completely superfluous